# Can I register all classes of a package as controllers in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have used, in my project, "springmvc-router" to remove @RequestMapping annotation from class definition.

Same way, is it possible to remove @Controller and @Service annotations in Class definitions?

Further, my package com.test.controllers include all contorllers annotated with @Controller and com.test.service.impl annotated with @Service.

Hence, can all classes under com.test.controllers be registered as controllers without @Controller?... The same follows for service annotation also.

Comment: No. The `@Controller` is a specific stereotype annotation to detect controllers which are processed for `@RequestMapping`. If you need detected you need at least `@Component` if you don't you need to configure each and every bean by hand in either XML or Java Config.

Comment: Also judging on the documentation of the springmvc-router project you still need the `@Controller` annotation for it to work properly.

Comment: At least, is there a possibility to add @Controller, just before compile or just before spring context load (using reflection...!), to certain package member classes? (I am using maven as dependency manager and build tool.)

Comment: Well you can with AspectJ but why? Why make things so complicated.

Comment: First reason is why simply annotate, if I know all the classes of package are controllers.

Comment: I would argue that your design is flawed (technical seperation instead of functional but alas). As stated y ou can do those things with AspectJ but it is like taking a canon to shoot a fly IMHO.

Comment: First reason is why simply annotate, if I know all the classes of package are controllers.

Second, rather embarrassing one is, other programmers are starters and may forget annotation or tamper with others' code and spend quite lot of time (including others' time) debugging and find out that they just missed an annotation !!!

If I have to with AspectJ, can you suggest a place to start with, to furnish the requirement?

Comment: Consider that a learning experience, you should teach them. By having it added automatically you don't teach them anything. They start to rely on (even more) magic to happen and things to automagically start to work. If it is hard to debug it might be time for redesign or more automated tests (faster feedback) in the first place. To learn more about AspectJ check its website and try to get introductions started. Also if they are starting to forget `@Controller` how are you going to force them to include the routing information? Or other thing they can forget?

Comment: Ok. I will consider that and have a discussion with my manager. :) Thanks.